# Show created and edited fields in Django admin form

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-modeladmin

I have this model

```
class Volunteer(models.Model):
STATUSES = (
    ('Active', 'Active'),
    ('Paused', 'Paused'),
    ('Inactive', 'Inactive'),
)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
email_address = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
picture = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUSES, default="Active")
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
edited = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
```

And I register it like this

```
class VolunteerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email_address', 'status', 'created', 'edited')
list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email_address', 'status')
list_editable = ('status',)
list_filter = ('status',)
search_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name')

admin.site.register(Volunteer, VolunteerAdmin)
```

I get an error because I have manually added the created and edited fields as I want to see them in the view/edit forms.  I know that the user should not be able to change these so I set the attributes to editable=False for both.  However, it throws an error.  Any idea what I need to do to be able to display these two fields in my admin forms?

This is my error:
'created' cannot be specified for Volunteer model form as it is a non-editable field. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class VolunteerAdmin.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you show your views.py ?

Comment: this is only a problem in the admin part.  I do not even have a view made for it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider adding **created** and **edited** in read-only fields like:

```
readonly_fields = ('created','edited')
```

Complete code snippet:

```
class VolunteerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email_address', 'status','created','edited')
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email_address', 'status')
    list_editable = ('status',)
    readonly_fields = ('created','edited')
    list_filter = ('status',)
    search_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name')

admin.site.register(Volunteer, VolunteerAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you could just get rid of the fields line ,add 'created', 'edited' to list of display if you want, usually you can see the field automatically in the detail of every volunteer,

maybe because you did it manually it got stuck, in that case  delete your last migration and database (sqlite) and re-do makemagrations and migrate.

also if you are usning a form in a forms.py to be used in a template you should exclude 'created',and  'edited', because you cant edit them.

Comment: This is only for the admin part.  I do not even have a view made yet.  When I remove the fields line, the page renders but does not include the added and edited fields.  I do not want to add them to the list_display because I don't want to see that data in the table, only on the record level.